# Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started]

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails

Thanks for Reply :) My web application configuration like grails 2.4.4 version, hibernate 4.3.6 final version along with spring-core-4.0.7.RELEASE.

i am performing like

```
Session session2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session2.persist(Obj);
session2.flush();
Transaction tx = session2.getTransaction();
                log.debug("ITS CREATED??")
                if(tx.isActive())
                {
                    log.debug("ITS ACTIVE")
                    if(!tx.wasCommitted())
                    {
                        log.debug("NOT COMMITTED")
                        tx.commit();
                    }else
                    {
                        log.debug(" COMMITTED")
                    }
                }else
                {
                    log.debug("NOT ACTIVE")
                }
```

Here when the execution is hitting the tx.commit() is throwing this kind of exception.

Am i missing something here? Please guide me.

Example:

```
class MetaDataController
{
def saveService;

def save={

 def returnParams = saveService.doSave(params);
 //Here returning to the controller, its giving an exception.

}
}


class SaveService
{
def transactional = true;

    def doSave(def params)
    {
        def params;
        Session session2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Metadata metaData =  new MetaData();
        ///Object association

        session2.persist(metaData);
        session2.flush();
        Transaction tx = session2.getTransaction();
        if(!tx.wasCommitted())
        {
            log.debug("NOT COMMITTED")
            tx.commit();
        }
        return params;

    }

}
```

Comment: The above code is running on service. After committing the value when returned to controller, its giving "Reason[Exception:org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started]" error.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Multiple threads will be trying to hit the grails controller, and business logic inside the grail service. Before come out of the service, i am trying to do an commit the current transaction, but its throwing an exception when its returning to controller..

Comment: Example :
class MetaDataController
{
def saveService;

def save={

 def returnParams = saveService.doSave(params);
 //Here returning to the controller, its giving an exception.

}
}


class SaveService
{
def transactional = true;

 def doSave(def params)
 {
  def params;
  Session session2 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

  Metadata metaData =  new MetaData();
  ///Object association

  session2.persist(metaData);
  session2.flush();
  Transaction tx = session2.getTransaction();
  if(!tx.wasCommitted())
  {
   log.debug("NOT COMMITTED")
   tx.commit();
  }
  return params;

 }

}

Comment: Please post that extra code in the question, not as a comment. It's unreadable as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess around with sessions and transactions for such a simple use case. You're using Grails, remember?

```
class SaveService
{
    def transactional = true;

    def doSave(def params)
    {
        Metadata metaData = new MetaData()
        metadata.save()
        return params // I don't get this, but what the hell.
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for yours valuable reply.